# GNU Assembler-Fortran Interface-Reg

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

```
       .386P
   
       .text                          # what is the correct syntax?
       .data                          # what is the correct syntax?
       .code                          # what is the correct syntax?
       start:
       pushl  %ebp
       movl   %ebp,%esp
       movb   %ah,0
 ?      les    %bx,dword ptr[%ebp+6]    # what is the correct syntax?
 ?      mov    al,%esi:[%ebx]           # what is the correct syntax?
   int    $16
   movl   %esp,%ebp
   pop    %ebp
   ret    $04
   exit:
```

This routine written for MS-DOS.

```
.386P
.MODEL  FLAT,FORTRAN
.DATA
.CODE
     PUBLIC SCREEN
SCREEN   PROC   FAR
                 PUSH   EBP
                 MOV    EBP,ESP
                 MOV    AH,0
                 LES    BX,DWORD PTR [EBP+6]
                 MOV    AL,ESI:[EBX]
                 INT    16
                 MOV    ESP,EBP
                 POP    EBP
                 RET    04
                 SCREEN ENDP
```

END

Now I want to convert it into Windows XP,32 Bit, Intel Centrino Core*2 Duo machine.

Waiting for early response.my email id:mastercomputerservices1957@gmail.com

I want particularly the above ? syntaxes at the earliest with all program.I have tried in many ways in many times,but failed.There are no working examples available regarding GNU Assembler.No body written the working examples.They given only lea examples without work.

please help me to learn further.After 40 years gap I am trying again.

Comment: Are you writing 16-bit code so you can run it in a Windows 16-bit NTVDM (DOS Box) or are you looking to make a Windows application? Are you trying to write a function to be called from Fortran? If you are what version of Fortran are you using It is unclear what you are really trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this is the MASM code you assembled? `MOV AL,ESI:[EBX]`
is invalid. Maybe it was meant to be ``MOV AL,ES:[EBX]` (ES instead of ESI)

Comment: GNU assembler syntax by default SRC, DEST rather than Intel's syntax where it is DEST, SRC. `LES BX,DWORD PTR [EBP+6]` would become `les 0x6(%ebp),%bx` and `MOV AL,ES:[EBX]` becomes `mov %es:(%ebx),%al` . Although that is how it would be encoded there are other issues in your code translation that are problematic and `int 16` isn't going to work in a Windows application since it is a BIOS interrupt. `movl   %ebp,%esp` should be `movl  %esp,%ebp` and `movb %ah,0` should be `movb $0, %ah`

Comment: Windows7,32Bit,IntelCentrino Core*2 Duo,Toshiba A205 Satellite,386 Pentium Laptop. binUtils:GNUAssemblerVersion2.9.4<i386-mingw32>using BFDversion2.9.4.NetBeans IDE7.4Version.As per your guidance related to GNU Assembler and solved my assembly routines,but unable to link my fortran project interface with assembly routines while linking object files.Assembly and fortran objects files generated,but giving error unresolved external files related to Assembly object files.
Please guide me further with your special experience in this matter.

Comment: As per your guidance I am 90% succeeded.But other 10% it is giving error..global _screen_ 
_screen_:
Pushl   %ebp
Movl    %ebp,%esp
Movb    $0,%ah
Les     6(%ebp),%bx
Mov     %es:(%ebx),%al
Int     $0x10
Movl    %esp,%ebp
Pop     %ebp
Ret     $04

Comment: .global _pixel_ 
_pixel_:
Pushl   %ebp
Movl    %ebp,%esp
Movb    $12,%ah
Les     14(%ebp),%bx
Mov     %es:(%ebx),%al
Les     10(%ebp),%bx
Mov     %es:(%ebx),%dx
Les     6(%ebp),%bx
Mov     %es:(%ebx),%cx
Int     $0x10 
Movl    %esp,%ebp
Pop     %ebp
Ret     $12

Comment: The following  error displays on the screen.

Comment: Program received signal sigsegv: segmentation fault-invalid memory reference.Backtrace for this error:#0    0x6f8aecb4  #1 0x6f89d642   #2 0x401138   waiting for your help to the above cited assembler troubles. I don't know the fault.

Comment: .global _screen_ 
_screen_:
Pushl   %ebp
Movl    %ebp,%esp
Movb    $0,%ah
Les     6(%ebp),%bx
Mov     %es:(%ebx),%al
Int     $0x10
Movl    %esp,%ebp
Pop     %ebp
Ret     $04
error is:Program received signal sigsegv: segmentation fault-invalid memory reference.
Backtrace for this error:
#0 0x6f8aecb4 
#1 0x6f89d642 
#2 0x401138 
waiting for your help to the above cited assembler troubles.

Comment: Well `Movl %ebp,%esp` is the wrong direction (operands are reversed) as well as the associated move at the end.

Comment: program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault -invalid memory reference.same error repeating.

Comment: .global _pixel_ 
_pixel_:
Pushl   %ebp
Movl    %esp,%ebp
Movb    $12,%ah
Les     14(%ebp),%bx
Mov     %es:(%ebx),%al
Les     10(%ebp),%bx
Mov     %es:(%ebx),%dx
Les     6(%ebp),%bx
Mov     %es:(%ebx),%cx
Int     $0x0A 
Movl    %esp,%ebp
Pop     %ebp
Ret     $12

Comment: .global _screen_ 
_screen_:
Pushl   %ebp
Movl    %esp,%ebp
Movb    $0,%ah
Les     6(%ebp),%bx
Mov     %es:(%ebx),%al
Int     $0x0A
Movl    %esp,%ebp
Pop     %ebp
Ret     $04

Comment: I couldn't find the fault,because there is no experience.If once error removes I will try the other routines with so much confidence.

Comment: Scrolling back through the comments you seem to be writing this code for Windows. I don't know the calling convention that it uses but it will be different than the one MS-DOS uses. For example the `LES` won't apply in Windows code since that is for segment:offset addressing in real mode. Parameters will be passed differently. I don't know the Fortran calling convention used on Windows so I can't really help.

Comment: sorry giving trouble

Comment: In Windows code you won't even be able to do `int 16` because that applies to a DOS/BIOS environment. This code you are trying to convert tries to change the screen mode and you can't do that in Windows like this.